# Using PersistentObject from Doctrine in Zend Framework

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

I have a question for you all. I'm just starting to use Zend Framework after I have used Codeigniter for about 1 year now. I have installed everything and everything is running now. But I have one problem. I want to use Doctrine for my modelling. And I always used the PersistentObject from Doctrine, but I can't seem to get it working.

The problem is that I need to pass through a ObjectManager to the PersistentObject. But I can't make it work. Does anybody have any idea how I can pass through the ObjectManger from the DoctrineORM module to the PersistentObject?

If I'm not clear enough you can tell me. It's a bit an hassle for me to speak english. I'm sorry about that!

Comment: There may be a few people here understanding that question, but i don't. Could you provide some code that you have tried? Maybe then i'd get an understanding of your concern. The ObjectManager can be fetched via `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');`

Comment: Sorry... Maybe i wasn't so clear in my question. I want to use the PersistentObject that is in Doctrine, therefore I must set the objectManger with the setObjectManager in the PersistentObject class. I don't want to do that in every Entity but I want to do that once. Therefore I must call the PersistentObject::setObjectManager somewhere in my code. But I don't know where to do it... I hope I'ts a bit clearer to you now!

Comment: You need to specify which version of Zend Framework 1 or 2 and also which version of Doctrine you are trying to implement wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I'm very sorry. It is ZendFramework 2 and Doctrine 2. But @timdev gave me the correct answer. Thanks for your time guys. I try my best to be clearer next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in your Module's onBootstrap() method:

```
<?php
namespace MyApplication;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject;

class Module {

    public function onBootstrap($e){
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        PersistentObject::setObjectManager($sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    }

}
```

Comment: You are the freaking best! Thank you very much. I think I need to learn more from the serviceManager. Is that a kind of registery in Zend framework 2?

Comment: Yes, the ServiceManager in ZF2 sort of replaces ZF1's Zend_Registry component -- and does a lot more.  The big difference is that instead of creating services during the bootstrap, you just register factories (or if there are no dependencies, register your classes as invokable).  So you get two main benefits: lazy-loading (classes aren't instantiated unless/until you need them), and some dependency management (defined in your factories).