# How do I configure a Doctrine2 entity which extends PersistentObject within Symfony2 project?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to be able to use the PersistentObject described here http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/a-doctrine-orm-odm-base-class.html during development of a Symfony2 project, to avoid creating and deleting getters and setters endlessly whilst the database and entity design are in flux.

Where in a Symfony2 project does one 'configure' the ObjectManager, as suggested in the brief documentation (code quote below)?  Should it be in the controller, and if so, what would it look like?

```
 $entityManager = EntityManager::create(...);
 PersistentObject::setObjectManager($entityManager);
```

I cannot find any working examples (although I did find this parallels example for the Zend2 framework on stackoverflow: [Using PersistentObject from Doctrine in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842640/using-persistentobject-from-doctrine-in-zend-framework)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PersistentObject](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/PersistentObject.php) is an object which you don't manually have to persist. It thereby provides **magic getters and setters** using php's `__call()` method.

You simply extend the Object in your entity class and use it inside your controller. without the need to generate getters and setters.

*example entity*

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourBundle\YourEntity;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject; 
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class YourEntity extends PersistentObject
{

   // i added the constructor in order to save the setObjectManager() 
   // call in the the controller

   public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
   {
       $this->setObjectManager($om);
   }

   /** 
    * @ORM\Id  
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
    */
   protected $name;

   // ... more properties

}
```

*example controller action*

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function yourAction($name)
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');

        $entity = new YourEntity($em);   // __construct calls setObjectManager($em)

        $entity->setName($name);         // magic setter is used here

        // ... no need for $em->persist($entity);

        $em->flush();                    // $entity is being persisted.
    }

    // ...
```

You get the doctrine entity manager inside  a symfony controller using one of ...

```
 $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();          // gets default manager
 $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default'); // same as above
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();            // using alias
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed but very clear example! This is really excellent. To take it further, in the case where the controller is using a query to fetch objects (e.g. via `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); $query = $em->createQuery($dql);`  how would the entity manager get passed to the  constructor method?