# Symfony2/Doctrine2 Inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm attempting to accomplish BASIC inheritance in Doctrine 2, but I'm running into several major issues.  Such a task should not be so complicated.  Let's get down to business...

I have three classes, BaseFoodType, Drink, and Snack.  My BaseFoodType has the following class definition:

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class BaseFoodType {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=7)
     */
    public $budget = 0;
}
```

Which follows the instructions for inheritance on the doctrine website: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Here is what the sub-classes look like prior to generating my entities:

```
namespace MySite\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MySite\MainBundle\Entity\EventDrink
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="drink")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Drink extends BaseFoodType {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=5, nullable=true)
     */
    public $people_count;
}
```

Both Drink, and Snack inherit from this base class but I'm running into numerous issues when attempting to build my entities using the doctrine:generate:entities command.  First, Symfony inserts a private "budget" property into each subclass, along with getters and setters (THIS DEFEATS THE PURPOSE INHERITANCE)

```
/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $budget;

/**
 * Set budget
 *
 * @param integer $budget
 */
public function setBudget($budget)
{
    $this->budget = $budget;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get budget
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getBudget()
{
    return $this->budget;
}
```

Second, I'm getting a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Access level to MySite\MainBundle\Entity\Drink::$budget
>   must be public (as in class MySite\MainBundle\Entity\BaseFoodType) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MySite\src\MySite\MainBundle\Entity\Drink.php on line
>   197

I could probably make the generated properties public and be on my way, but again, that defeats the purpose of inheritance!

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: `BaseFoodType::budget` should be protected not public ... show us your entities Drink and Snack please

Comment: nifr: The property is set to public for a reason.

Comment: the reason of having public properties instead of getters/setters against conventions?

Comment: Because I'm using php's "get_object_vars" function to get all of the public properties of my classes for auto-magic display in the UI.

Comment: This can be solved better but let's leave out this discussion for now. provide your entities and phrase a clear question please :)

Comment: I posted one of the base classes above, both are identical for the time being... and honestly, I'm not sure how much more clear I can be.  In fact, I could word it in a single sentence: "How do I Accomplish BASIC Inheritance in Doctrine 2"

Comment: what do you mean by "Symfony inserts a private "budget" property in each subclass" ... where is the exception thrown? using which implementation / command ?

Comment: I mean exactly what I said.  It inserted a private budget property into each subclass along with corresponding getters and setters.  You seem to be more of a visual person, so I posted the code above.  Thanks for taking a look, none-the-less.

Comment: `doctrine:generate:entities` generates getters/setters for private/protected/public properties .. that's the purpose of this command what's your problem with that? if auto-generation doesn't work for you just write the class yourself like you want it to be. or am i missing something here? If BaseFoodType has a public property .. jeah you can't make it private in Drink or Snack ... basic inheritance

Comment: Right, but why would it ADD private properties and getters/setters from properties that are inherited into base classes?  That seems absurd.

Comment: I didn't make anything private in Drink or Snack, DOCTRINE did that automatically.

Comment: There are no getters/setters in your parent class maybe the auto-generation does not take your public property into account ... nevermind ... you can fix your class to reflect your non-standard public property behavior in a second. What's the other problem you have? Feel free to submit a pull request to https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle if you think the behavior of /blob/master/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php can be improved :)

Comment: Not a bad idea.  I'll take a look at that later today.  For now, I just removed the generated private variables and methods from the sub-classes, and added getters and setters to the super class.

Comment: By the way ... if you want all private/protected properties to be returned by a getter method you could just implement something like `public function getVars() { get_class_vars(get_class($this)); }` in BaseFoodType and loop over the output in your template ... without the need for your public properties ... and the doctrine "error"

Comment: .... and have a look at my answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089307/how-do-i-configure-a-doctrine2-entity-which-extends-persistentobject-within-symf/17096943#17096943 ... maybe you can learn something new from it :D

Comment: i have provided an answer, please accept it as it explains ( and provides a solution to ) the exception quoted in your question. This might be helpful for other users in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that sounds helpful.  Your suggestion to use get_class_vars will not work in my case, as I have other instance variables that I DO NOT want to display.  I'm using the 'unconventional' public properties as a means to flag which properties should be returned to display via get_object_vars.

Comment: you could use array_filter before returning the array

Comment: @nifr your answer is only partial. It does explain, very well, how to change some default behaviours of the entity generator but it doesn't help solve the problem of not wanting to see all of the inherited fields back in the subclass.

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine provides the means to specify the visibility of generated fields. Either protected or private. The default is private.

The problem is that the Symfony command that invokes Doctrine offers no way to change this.

Creating your own subclass of the standard Symfony command will allow you more control over the generation process. This might help you along.

```
namespace Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Command;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command as DC;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator;

class GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand extends DC\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();
        $this->setName('foo:generate:entities');
    }

    /**
     * get a doctrine entity generator
     *
     * @return EntityGenerator
     */
    protected function getEntityGenerator()
    {
        $entityGenerator = new EntityGenerator();
        $entityGenerator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
        $entityGenerator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
        $entityGenerator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(false);
        $entityGenerator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
        $entityGenerator->setNumSpaces(4);
        $entityGenerator->setAnnotationPrefix('ORM\\');
        $entityGenerator->setFieldVisibility($entityGenerator::FIELD_VISIBLE_PROTECTED);

        return $entityGenerator;
    }
}
```

This does two things. It sets the property visibility to protected. This prevents php errors.

`$entityGenerator->setFieldVisibility($entityGenerator::FIELD_VISIBLE_PROTECTED);`

It also  copies the annotations from mapped super class into the entity class.

`$entityGenerator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);`

Here's some example code where properties are inherited from a base class and their visibility and annotations copy correctly into the inheriting class

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class DataSuper {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Campaign", inversedBy="data")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Exclude
     */
    protected $campaign;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true, name="data")
     */
    protected $data;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdDate;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\DataRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="data")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("none")
 */
class Data extends DataSuper
{
}
```

After generation the Data class looks like:

```
class Data extends DataSuper
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
 */
protected $data;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="createdDate", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
protected $createdDate;

/**
 * @var \Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\Campaign
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\Campaign", inversedBy="data")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
protected $campaign;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set data
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return Data
 */
public function setData($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get data
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

/**
 * Set createdDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdDate
 * @return Data
 */
public function setCreatedDate($createdDate)
{
    $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getCreatedDate()
{
    return $this->createdDate;
}

/**
 * Set campaign
 *
 * @param \Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\Campaign $campaign
 * @return Data
 */
public function setCampaign(\Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\Campaign $campaign = null)
{
    $this->campaign = $campaign;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get campaign
 *
 * @return \Foo\Bundle\FooBundle\Entity\Campaign 
 */
public function getCampaign()
{
    return $this->campaign;
}
}
```

And the table structure is correct once you do:

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown because `BaseFoodType::budget` is a **public** property and `doctrine:generate:entities` created a **private** property in your Drink / Snack classes extending BaseFoodType ( which is not correct but the way the command works by now ).

Property visibility in a subclass can only be the same level or more liberate ( private -> protected -> public ) but never more restrictive.

[**doctrine:generate:entities**](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php) did not take superclass's public property into account when generating the getters/setters as the implementation with a public property is non-standard.

Therefore you will have to adjust the generated class manually.

I recommend using private/protected properties combined with getters & setters.