# Proper way to update class object in db using symfony2 + doctrine + form?

Tags: forms, class, symfony, doctrine, updating

I have a simple class:

```
class Type
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $name;

    ... 
}
```

And have a some 'type' objects in database.
So, if i want to change one of them, i create new controller rule (like /types/edit/{id}) and new action:

```
public function typesEditViewAction($id)
{   
    ... 
    $editedType = new Type();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($editedType)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('id', 'hidden', array('data' => $id))
        ->getForm();

    // send form to twig template
    ...
}
```

After that, i create another controller rule (like /types/do_edit) and action:

```
public function typesEditAction(Request $request)
{   
    ... 
    $editedType = new Type();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($editedType)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm();

    $form->bind($request); // <--- ERROR THERE !!!

    // change 'type' object in db
    ...
}
```

And i found a small problem there.
Сlass 'Type' doesn't have аuto-generated setter setId() and on binding i got error.

```
Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "setId()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Lan\CsmBundle\Entity\Type".
```

Now, i remove 'id' field from symfony2 form object ($form) and transmit it manually to template.
At second controller's action i have $form object and 'id'-field apart.
I don't know a 'proper'-way for doing that (updating 'type' class). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony has an integrated [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) which automatically fetches your entity from database and throws an Exception ( which you can catch in a listener ) if the entity is not found.

You can easily handle GET and POST requests in one controller method.

**make sure you have the public getters and setters for your properties in your entity.**

I added annotations to make the routing clearer and still have a working example.

```
use Vendor\YourBundle\Entity\Type;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

// ...

/** 
 *  @Route("/edit/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 *  @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Type $type)
{   

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($type)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
         $form->bind($request);

         if ($form->isValid())
         {
              $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
              $em->flush();          // entity is already persisted and managed by doctrine.

              // return success response
         }
    }

    // return the form ( will include the errors if validation failed )
}
```

I strongly suggest you should create a [form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) to further simplify your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your support for all my questions today :)

Comment: p.s. and one moment. So I must create a setter for id? I don't know why symfony can't auto-generate setter for ID field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089307/how-do-i-configure-a-doctrine2-entity-which-extends-persistentobject-within-symf ... See my answer over here on how to use Doctrine's PersistentObject if you don't want to create getters and setters for your entities but i don't recommend it. with IDE integration (Eclipse PDT Extras, Sublime via Plugin, PHPStorm all have auto-generation methods ) or `doctrine:generate:entities` command it's really just a matter of seconds to generate some getters/setters.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stumbling on this where you added the ID field to your FormType because the frontend needed it you can just set the ID column to "not-mapped" like so:

```
->add('my_field', 'hidden', ['mapped'=>false])
```

and it prevents the ID value trying to get used by the form processing method.